# Format Saml2SecurityToken xml to include saml in tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am kinda starter with SAML stuff.
I have written a code to get Saml2SecurityToken in file in xml format. However xml I am getting does not include SAML in the tags.

Actual :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Assertion ID="_750e2198-2802-43ed-a6a8-3c991cdd1531" IssueInstant="2014-12-05T13:13:22.822Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
           .....
    </Assertion>
```

Expected :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_7cfb8b12d1b08367d163fea9c81d8e98" IssueInstant="2014-03-20T17:54:10.107Z" Version="2.0">
        <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">THE_ISSUER_ID (Typically a URL)</saml2:Issuer>
        <saml2p:Status>
            <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
        </saml2p:Status>
        <saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_23dcb09d50ddf580e2186836c0ffddff" IssueInstant="2014-03-20T17:54:10.099Z" Version="2.0">
             .......
        </saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Here is the code which I have written to generate security token and write to file:

```
 public static void SsoRequest(string content, string arguments)
        {
            try
            {
                string identifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                string _privateCertificatepath = Engine.ConfigFiles[SSO.SAMLConfigurationName]["PrivateCertificatePath"].Value;
                byte[] _certificateByte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_privateCertificatepath);
                string password = Engine.ConfigFiles[SSO.SAMLConfigurationName]["CertificatePassword"].Value; ;
                string opfilepath = @"C:\test.xml";

                Saml2SecurityToken token = GetSamlAssertionSignedWithCertificate(identifier, password, _certificateByte);
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(opfilepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                XmlWriter xmlwriter = XmlWriter.Create(HttpContext.Current.Response.Output);
                Saml2SecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler();
                tokenHandler.WriteToken(xmlwriter, token);
                xmlwriter.Flush();
                xmlwriter.Close();
                fs.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("index.aspx", true);
        }



 public static Saml2SecurityToken GetSamlAssertionSignedWithCertificate(String nameIdentifierClaim, String password, Byte[] _certificateByte)
        {
            Saml2Assertion assertion = new Saml2Assertion(new Saml2NameIdentifier("http://www.example.com/"));
            Saml2Conditions conditions = new Saml2Conditions();
            conditions.NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow;
            conditions.NotOnOrAfter = DateTime.MaxValue;
            assertion.Conditions = conditions;

            Saml2Subject subject = new Saml2Subject();
            subject.SubjectConfirmations.Add(new Saml2SubjectConfirmation(Saml2Constants.ConfirmationMethods.Bearer));
            subject.NameId = new Saml2NameIdentifier(nameIdentifierClaim);
            assertion.Subject = subject;

            X509Certificate2 _cert = new X509Certificate2(_certificateByte, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            X509SigningCredentials clientSigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(_cert);
            assertion.SigningCredentials = clientSigningCredentials;
            return new Saml2SecurityToken(assertion);
        }
```

Am I missing something here? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least from an XML perspective, you shouldn't need it. XML namespaces can be specified using whatever alias is handy, including the empty/default alias, as long as the xmlns points to the correct URI. The URI (in this case, the Oasis SAML URN) is the only thing that should matter.

So these four elements are XML-equivalent, and most XML libraries won't even provide a way to tell the difference:

```
<Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" …

<saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" …

<fnord:Assertion xmlns:fnord="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" …

<!-- by convention & convenience aliases are usually lowercase, 
     but don't have to be -->
<ZB:Assertion xmlns:ZB="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" …
```

Anything that requires a specific namespace alias is probably someone doing their own (buggy) XML parsing rather than using a standard library, which makes their whole SOAP and SAML stack suspect.